# AngularJS - Animate ng-click transitions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm following a common Angular animate pattern that's basically a toggle based on a Boolean value.

The problem is that the animation works on ng-click, but the next ng-click only removes the classes. The third ng-click fires the animation again, and so on.

I need a way to have the animation transition on every ng-click. Is there a way to remove the animation classes once the animation is finished, or is there a better way to approach this that doesn't rely on the true/false functionality of movieAnimateIn (see below).

The content is all dynamic based on JSON data.

My next button:

```
<a href="#" class="button" ng-click="nextMovie(); fadeIn();">Next</a>
```

My element to animate:

```
<div class="movie-cover animated" ng-class="{fadeInUp:movieAnimateIn}">
```

My code in the directive:

```
this.fadeIn = function() {
    this.movieAnimateIn = !this.movieAnimateIn;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you not including/using [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)?

Comment: I am, and the animation is working fine, but I can't figure out how to have it fire every time instead of every other time. For example, a user clicks and the animation fires because movieAnimateIn is changed to true; a user clicks again and movieAnimateIn is changed to false, removing the classes but not animating it.